# What is the Elo rating of a chess computer that can only look 1, 2, 3, ... moves ahead

Tags: engines, rating, ply

Has anyone calculated the average Elo rating of a chess computer as a function of the number of half moves or plys ahead it can look. I realise that the Elo is also a function of the choice of move then taken which may differ from engine to engine.

Comment: This is likely (if not guaranteed) to be very different for each major chess engine.

Comment: Yes I mention that in the question. I am really just looking for an average estimate.

Answer (score 13):

There is a paper, which examines this relationship for Houdini 1.5.

http://web.ist.utl.pt/diogo.ferreira/papers/ferreira13impact.pdf

On page 77 you get the relevant table:

```
depth (ply): elo:

20    2894

19    2828

18    2761

17    2695

16    2629

15    2563

…

8     2099

7     2033

6     1966
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an area that academic can write papers on it. The relationships is complicated and might not be quantified.

Essentially, it's a non-linear relationship where the improvement is most obvious in shallow depth. The benefit diminishes as the engine go deeper and deeper in the search.

Reference: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Depth

Look for the "Diminishing Returns" section and you'll know more.

Comment: Thanks for that reference. It provides some useful relative advantages between a n-ply and an n+1-ply engine. I was looking for an absolute Elo but I accept now that that may not be possible.

Comment: Absolute Elo is not possible because it varies from one engine to another. There is simply no formula.